# Does the central limit theorem state that if $Y_i$ is i.i.d. and *n* is sufficiently large then we can assume that $Y_i$ is normally distributed?

Tags: statistics

Does the central limit theorem state that if  $Y_i$ is i. i. d. and *n* is sufficiently large then we can assume that $Y_i$ is normally distributed?

Answer (score 0):

No. It doesn't change the distribution of the observations. It says that:

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{Y}-\mu\right)\to^{d} N(0, \sigma^2) \quad \text{as}\quad n\to\infty.
$$

So the sample average (and similarly, the sum) of the observations $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ tends to a normal distribution as the sample size tends to infinity. This is commonly interpreted on basic level classes in statistics as the sample mean being approximately normally distributed if the sample size is large. In other words, it says nothing about the distribution of the observations $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ -- they are still distributed according to the distribution we started out with.